# Configuration-driven, Text Based Configuration Wizard for Linux

Tags: linux, configuration, ncurses, curses

Is there a curses based system for building a configuration-file driven setup wizard?  I'd like something that allows me to simply input a configuration file (debconf-style or XML-based) and output a populated configuration file.

I've done some searching, but most of what I find are tools for specific purposes (linux kernel menuconfig, etc).  Is there a generic tool for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

- [Dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/) - Script driven curses widgets
- [CDK](http://invisible-island.net/cdk/cdk.html) - Curses Development Kit
- [Newt/Whiptail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt_%28programming_library%29) - Programming lib and util for text based windows and components